# Ckeditor inline editor <p> tags being added on init despite presence of <h2> tag

Tags: ckeditor4.x

SOLVED. Update - I was mistaken in my original assumption. See my answer below.

I have an app where I initialise inline ckeditors on various contenteditable divs.

I am well aware that CKEditor needs to add

```
<p><br><p>
```

to the markup of an empty editor to prevent content collapse, however I have a specific situation where contenteditable div that contains ONLY this html:

```
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
```

Has its markup modified to this:

```
<p><br></p><h2>This is a heading</h2><p><br></p>
```

When I call

```
CKEDITOR.inline(element, config);
```

Where element is the contenteditable div

I am using 4.4.1

This only happens when the markup in the contenteditable div is purely a heading. If there is also a paragraph in the markup this does not happen.
It appears that CKEditor is ignoring the heading when determining whether or not it needs to add content to an empty editor.

To be clear everything else works as I would expect, just this very specific issue.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out this was not ckeditor at all but some of my own code that was adding the

tags.

I had some script which was checking whether the innerHtml of the element was a p tag, and if not, it was wrapping the whole thing in p tags.

The reason this was not more obvious is because the p tags were empty and hence collapsed. Only when calling CKEDITOR.inline(element, config) on the element did CKEditor do its thing and fillEmptyBlocks, which created the height of the p  tags. This seemed then that they only appeared when the editor was instantiated.

In fact they were there already.